# How to make this delete query more efficient in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have this query, which runs in about 0.1 seconds in a table with over 100,000 records, which I think is good (d1 and d2 are indexed)

```
SELECT key_id
FROM `info`
WHERE d1 > 10 AND d1 < 20 AND d2 > 5 AND d2 < 15
GROUP BY `key_id`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 300;
```

Now I want to delete all these key_id from another table, so I tried this:

```
DELETE FROM `keys` WHERE id IN (<first query>)
```

The keys table has around 7,000 rows. I've read that the subquery evaluates everytime, so it's running 7000 times, 0.1 seconds each ~= 700 seconds. Terribly slow. Haven't let it finish tho, so I'm not sure if it takes 700 seconds. What I know for sure is that it takes more than 30 secs.

How can I improve this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a JOIN instead of subquery

```
DELETE keys
FROM keys
JOIN (<first query>) AS i
ON k.id = i.key_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a join

```
DELETE FROM `keys` 
INNER JOIN ( 
SELECT key_id
FROM `info`
WHERE d1 > 10 AND d1 < 20 AND d2 > 5 AND d2 < 15
GROUP BY `key_id`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 300) t on t.key_id = `keys`.id;
```

Comment: I think you'd need to add " `\`keys\`.*` " between "`DELETE`" and "`FROM`" keywords. (I'm not entirely sure that's required, but that's the way I always do it. Might be because I *always* write it as a `SELECT \`keys\`.* FROM` first, to verify the rows I'm going to be deleting, and often saving the resultset, before I replace the `SELECT` keyword with `DELETE`. Just in case.

Comment: @spencer7593  for what i remember is not required * or other column name .. because delete work anyway on the row ..  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

Comment: I get confused, because the multitable DELETE syntax is different on Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, et al.

Comment: @spencer7593   .. right, even I get confused sometimes